# Google Calendar Laravel Api

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I have a problem connecting the calendar with laravel, the message what was before are the invalid credentials and I redo my credentials of my api in google console so I have a new, I already make the aouth redirects urls and put, the tutorial I use was that https://github.com/webdevmatics/GoogleCalendarApi, all work fine but I click in redo secret and well that change the id secret I think but I already make all again I still not working this is my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Google_Client;
use Google_Service_Calendar;
use Google_Service_Calendar_Event;
use Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Patients;
class CalendarController extends Controller
{
protected $client;

public function __construct()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig('google_calendar.json');
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);

    $guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array('curl' => array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false)));
    $client->setHttpClient($guzzleClient);
    $this->client = $client;
}

public function view(){
    return view('calendar.index');
}

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
        $this->client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($this->client);

        $calendarId = 'primary';

        $results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId);
        return $results->getItems();

    } else {
        return redirect()->route('oauthCallback');
    }

}

public function oauth()
{
    session_start();

    $rurl = action('CalendarController@oauth');
    $this->client->setRedirectUri($rurl);
    if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $auth_url = $this->client->createAuthUrl();
        $filtered_url = filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        return redirect($filtered_url);
    } else {
        $this->client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $this->client->getAccessToken();
        return redirect()->route('cal.index');
    }
}
```

That is my controller, the google_calendar.json is the file what you download in the credentials, and the error is the next

[image]

[image]

[image]

and my code for get the events in the jquery is the next

```
$('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,listYear'
  },

  displayEventTime: false, // don't show the time column in list view

  events: 'gcalendar',

  eventClick: function(event) {
    // opens events in a popup window
    window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
    return false;
  },

  loading: function(bool) {
    $('#loading').toggle(bool);
  }

});
```

And my routes are the next

```
Route::resource('gcalendar', 'CalendarController');
Route::get('/calendar', 'CalendarController@view')->name('calendar');
Route::get('/calendar/oauth', 'CalendarController@oauth')->name('oauthCallback');
```

Sorry if I not very explanatory, I don't understand very well the problem, I already tried many things, any helps thanks

You can view the demo project here http://clinic-data.vlmg.mx/ the user is admin@admin.com and the pass is admin, regards